# How can I make a button in the header load an iFrame content

Tags: javascript, html

Being very new to coding and HTML i am very much struggling to get the login button in the header to load an iframe when clicked

I would be very grateful if some one could help me out

`````
  <header class="header-area header-sticky wow slideInDown" data-wow-duration="0.75s" data-wow-delay="0s">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <nav class="main-nav">
            <!-- ***** Logo Start ***** -->
            <a href="index.html" class="logo">
              <img src="logo-v1.png" alt="">             
            </a>
            <!-- ***** Logo End ***** -->
            <!-- ***** Menu Start ***** -->
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#top" class="active">Home</a></li>
              <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
              <li class="scroll-to-section"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
              <li class="scroll-to-section"><div class="border-first-button"><a href="#contact">login</a></div></li> 
            </ul>        
            <a class='menu-trigger'>
                <span>Menu</span>
            </a>
            <!-- ***** Menu End ***** -->
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- ***** Header Area End ***** -->````
`````